# Проблема с импортом изображение

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Пожалуйста помогите, заранее спасибо)

[image: Здесь произвожу импорт изображений]

[image: Здесь я пробовал двумя способами испортить но ничего не получается]

[image: Ошибка выглядит так]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]